# Reading pig scheme/header to understand the order of fields in a tuple

Tags: apache-pig, udf, pig-udf

Is there a way to get access to .pig_schema or .pig_header value into a pig java udf, so that I know which field name is being parsed.

I work on an `PigStorage` output generated by a different process and it keep changing rapidly. I want to make as many less changes as possible due to these changes.

For example : previous format would like like - `{name:chararray, age:INT, salary:DOUBLE}`

current format would look like - `{sex:chararray, name:chararray, age:INT, salary:Double }`.

In my udf i am only interested in name and salary, but the order in which they are given as my input can vary as stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I've seen in the Pig code, since 0.11, Pig has schema tuples. With the `schematuple.udf` option set (default), schema is passed to UDF functions, and can be obtained within the UDF `exec()` method calling `getInputSchema()`. When you get the schema, you'll get the names of the different elements of the schema. You can then select the fields you want based on their name.